# How can I find previous version of NPM @types

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

I am using Angular 1.4.7 and I am trying to find a type file for this version.

On the [NPM site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angularjs) I have searched for AngularJs and found version 1.5.14 alpha. How can I get a list of all versions published to @types/npm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run:

```
$ npm info @types/angular

{ name: '@types/angular',
  description: 'TypeScript definitions for Angular JS 1.5',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '1.5.16' },
  versions: 
   [ '1.5.1-alpha',
     '1.5.2-alpha',
     '1.5.3-alpha',
     '1.5.4-alpha',
     '1.5.5-alpha',
     '1.5.6-alpha',
     '1.5.7',
     '1.5.8',
     '1.5.9',
     '1.5.10',
     ...
```

you'll see list of all available versions for this package. For `angular` the oldest is `1.5.1-alpha` so you probably have to install typings from a different source with `typings` tool.

Comment: I have tried to find previous versions with typings but with no luck